# Can not add iOS bundle identifier

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I have seen other similar posts for this and no response from LinkedIn yet (and they direct you here for support).  I have an app for both iOS & Android, com.witopia.securemyemail - I am using the package name for Android, but whenever I try to add the iOS bundle identifier (of the same name), I receive: "Your changes could not be saved right now, please try again."  We have checked with all of our developers and can not find this name used any place else.  Is there any way we can look this up and see if it's being used by some other account? Or a way to obtain more detailed error reporting as to the issue with the name?  We are using the same bundle identifier in xCode as well as iTunes Connect for our App so I doubt some other developer has taken it, but who knows...

Comment: How is this connected with LinkedIn? You have not made clear what you were doing when this message appeared. In a web site? What web site? What page?

Comment: If you are sure about the bundle identifier not being used by someone, you can always raise an issue with apple and look for resolution.

Comment: Sorry its not clear, I thought tagging this "linkedin", with a specific LinkedIn error message would indicate I'm trying to add the iOS bundle identifier within the SDK settings for my App at developer.linkedin.com.  This has nothing to do with Apple or iTunes Connect.

Comment: This has been resolved. We finally found it listed in a developers personal LinkedIn account.  It would be nice if LinkedIn had a way to look up the iOS bundle identifiers and notify/contact the person who registered the iOS bundle identifier to save all this hassle.

Answer (score 1):

**Error:- "Your changes could not be saved right now, please try again." - LinkedIn Developer Account.**
I also created the same for Android and raised to Linkedin help center but after so many conversations finally, I got the reply which is in a screenshot.
I am also unable to update my application package name & hash in the LinkedIn Developer.

We have to wait until this issue not will be solved by a LinkedIn technical team.

[image]